# How to load column data from DataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm porting application to ASP.Net 5.0 with EF7 and found several problems. One of the issues is MS have dropped DataTable. I'm trying to transfer a bit of code to not use DataTable but read from SQLDataReader and record this into entities I have. I have to read data by columns, but looks like datareader can read only once.

The old code:

```
           Series[] arrSeries = new Series[dt.Columns.Count - 1];

                IList<Categories> arrCats = new List<Categories>();
                Categories arrCat = new Categories();


                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    var strarr = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row[dc.Ordinal]).ToList();
                    if (dc.Ordinal == 0)
                    {
                        arrCat.category = strarr.Select(o => new Category { label = o.ToString() }).ToList();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Series s = new Series()
                        {
                            seriesname = dc.ColumnName,
                            renderas = null,
                            showvalues = false,
                            data = strarr.Select(o => new SeriesValue { value = o.ToString() }).ToList()
                        };

                        arrSeries[dc.Ordinal - 1] = s;
                    }
                }

                arrCats.Add(arrCat);

                MultiFusionChart fusChart = new MultiFusionChart
                {
                    chart = dictAtts,
                    categories = arrCats,
                    dataset = arrSeries
                };
                return fusChart;
```

The new code:

```
                    Series[] arrSeries = new Series[colColl.Count - 1];

                    IList<Categories> arrCats = new List<Categories>();
                    Categories arrCat = new Categories();
                    arrCat.category = new List<Category>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        Series s = new Series()
                        {
                            seriesname = reader.GetName(i),
                            renderas = null,
                            showvalues = false
                        };

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                Category cat = new Category();
                                cat.label = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                                arrCat.category.Add(cat);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                SeriesValue sv = new SeriesValue();
                                sv.value = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                                s.data.Add(sv);

                                arrSeries[i - 1] = s;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    arrCats.Add(arrCat);

                    MultiFusionChart fusChart = new MultiFusionChart
                    {
                        chart = dictAtts,
                        categories = arrCats,
                        dataset = arrSeries
                    };
                    return fusChart;
```

Where the code works, it returns null for Series. And I believe this is because reader went to the end while recording Categories. As far as I know it is not possible to reset DataReader?

Is there a way to load column data from DataReader to List? Or maybe there is other way how I can replace DataTable in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `value` from multiple `columns` by specifying its `index` like this

```
int totalColumns = reader.FieldCount;
for(int i=0;i<totalColumns;i++)
{
 var label = reader.GetValue(i);  
}
```

You can select value of all columns by looping through columns.

> **`GetValue`** takes `int` as `argument` which is `index` of column not the `index of row`.

Comment: The problem is that I never know how many columns I will have. That is why I'm looking for the solution to get all values from one column, and then from another, etc...

Comment: Plz check the answer now if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop. At first when your i is 0, You have initialized a 'Series` object S. After that,

```
while (reader.Read())
```

will read your entire Reader while your i will still be zero. SO only the

```
if(i == 0)
```

condition will return true and your entire reader will be spent. Afterwards, for i >= 1,

```
while (reader.Read())
```

will always return false keeping your array, **arrSeries** blank. Remove the while loop and directly read value from the dataReader using the index,

```
reader.GetValue(i);
```